# Shelf Life of Methylcyclopentadiene

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, organometallic-compounds

We are making organometallics in the lab, but instead of just regular Cyclopentadiene dimer, we crack methylcyclopentadiene dimer to make methylcyclopentadiene.

I cannot find the shelf life of methylcyclopentadiene, because we are going to be using a lot, and it takes quite a bit of time to make, and we need to make some in advance.

Does anyone happen to know the shelf life of methycyclopentadiene?

Thanks!

Comment: If you google "methylcyclopentadiene, rate of dimerization" you will find some useful links.  [This one](http://www.vurup.sk/sites/vurup.sk/archivedsite/www.vurup.sk/pc/vol52_2010/issue4/pdf/pc_4_2010_krupka_098.pdf) provides the rate constant and activation energy for the dimerization of MeCPD, with this information you can calculate the shelf half-life at your storage temperature.

Comment: [This link](https://books.google.com/books?id=6yB2BSYfJUcC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=methylcyclopentadiene,+rate+of+dimerization&source=bl&ots=ZpFJiTiRYy&sig=rwgVj3QT-w9tsvv26exf1LRuw8Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAWoVChMIi9un2f3TyAIVBuVjCh0mmw0r#v=onepage&q=methylcyclopentadiene%2C%20rate%20of%20dimerization&f=false) says that MeCPD can be stored at -30 °C for a few days.